# Are there theoretical attacks against ECC Digital Signatures?

Tags: attacks, digital-signature, ecc

I was asked to do a research about attacks on various digital signature schemes.  There is one thing that bothers me for which I could not find a direct answer.

For digital signatures that are based on prime numbers (like RSA) attacks are theoretic for example "chosen ciphertext attack" or "known plaintext attack", a very good source could be "[Twenty years of attacks on RSA cryptosystem](http://www.ams.org/notices/199902/boneh.pdf)"

For Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) based digital signatures attacks are purely physical, for example "fault attacks" or "side-channel attacks", a typical source is "[A survey of fault attacks](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/46299100_A_Survey_on_Fault_Attacks/file/e0b4952c1f3df1bc58.pdf)"

Why there are no theoretic attacks on ECC? the reason that answer is important for me is because I am supposed to implement an attack for a specific ECC digital signature.  Since it is not implemented on an actual device (at least yet) I can't do that (attacks are physical) and I can't figure another similar work as my guideline.

I barely managed to find some few paragraphs like this "The main reason for the attractiveness of ECC is the fact that there is no sub-exponential algorithm known to solve the discrete logarithm problem on a properly chosen elliptic curve" is this the reason? or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Look up batch cracking attacks and the attacks that have an effect of squaring the key space in security

Comment: "chosen ciphertext attack" isn't really an attack. It's more like an attack model.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of pitfalls with ECC:

- Invalid curve attacks: Attacker encodes a point which is not on the curve and has low order. Deadly attack on Diffie-Hellman. I don't think this can be exploited with ECDSA since there is no attacker controlled point.
- Point on twist on a non twist secure curve: Same as above, but works for compressed points as well.
- Incorrect handing of special cases: Traditional ECC addition formulas need to handle several special cases. It's easy to forgot one.
- (EC)DSA needs a uniformly distributed per-signature value. Using the same value twice or using a guessable value leads to key recovery. Even a small bias can lead to key recovery if enough signatures are known by the attacker. [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) describes a deterministic generation method.
- Applications relying on unusual properties the signature scheme doesn't provide. For example signatures are malleable, which caught some bitcoin applications by surprise.

Comment: I love reading your answers.